# Solution file vs. Project file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Can someone briefly explain to me the difference between Visual Studio's solution file (.sln) and project file (.vcproj).

It seems to me opening either one open the correct solution/project in Visual Studio.  Is one the super-set of the other?

Note: I am currently using Visual Studio 2008 working on a project that was brought forward from Visual Studio 2005 (I believe).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A solution is a set of projects. If you need more than one project in your software, then go with solutions. I.E.: A Class Library Project + A Web Application Project.

Answer (score 4):

A project file typically corresponds to a single module: EXE or DLL or LIB.  A solution manages a collection of project files.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is a collection of projects. Visual Studio is made so that it cannot function without a solution, so if you open a bare project, it will generate the solution automatically (or try to find one).

Answer (score 2):

One solution can contain zero or more projects. Everything is in projects, so a solution with zero projects doesn't contain anything at all besides the solution properties.

Visual studio keeps track of where the projects are used, so if you open a project file, it will open (IIRC) the last solution where it was used.

When you create a project from scratch, a solution is also created, but it's not shown until you add another project to it. It looks like you have only the project open, but it's actually a solution containing the project that is open.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically project files are intended to contain the data required to build the files in the project into an exe or dll.  This file is utilized by the local compilers or with systems such as Team Foundation system and server side build agents.

Solutions are a client (IDE) construct designed to manage collections of projects, which in effect is a collection of different build definitions and associated files.

Comment: This question has already been answered (6 years ago), but welcome to Stack Overflow nonetheless! :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution files are typically made up of multiple project files.